# Ajax.actionlink is working even if the application is not running

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

i have the following Ajax.actionlink that delete an object:-

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer",
        new { id = answer.AnswersID },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete this Answer ?",
              HttpMethod = "Post",
              UpdateTargetId = @answer.AnswersID.ToString(),
              OnSuccess = "removePartial2",
          })
```

and the following removePartial2 java script that will be called Onsuccess:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removePartial2() {
        alert('Deletion was successful'); 
        $(this).remove();
}
</script>
```

i wanted to test how the ajax action link will work if i application is not running ,, so i stopped debugging the application from the visual web developer , but i noticed that even if i stop debugging the application the ajax link will still delete the objects successfully from the database but the `alert('Deletion was successful')` will not be shown,, **so what might cause this unsual behaviour ?**

Comment: So you're saying you're navigating to the Delete Action directly? Your website is still live in IIS even if it is not "running" from visual studio. EDIT: Unless you are using the built in server. But still, not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Perhaps the "Delete" action response allowed itself to be cached at the client. Try clearing your browser cache?

Answer (score 1):

If you are debugging in Visual Studio, when you stop debugging, your application will **continue** to run until you stop the ASP.NET Develpoment Server, So Your DB code will still run until you quit VS or exit the Server (in the tray, right click -> stop)